# How can I write a unit test against a WebPartBase class and mock out the controls?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, tdd, web-parts

I have a bunch of **WebPartBase** classes that I'm trying to invoke a method on. Some of the methods call controls on the UI. I want to stub out those controls somehow so that an exception doesn't get thrown when attempting to set values on them. Does anyone know of a good way to do this? It would also be fine if they were initialized but I'm not sure how to initialize them without running a web server.

My test code looks like this. **IntializeOnAdd()** is a method on **KPIWebPartBase** and **KPIWebPartBase** inherits from **WebPartBase**.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void InvokeAllWidgets()
        {
            var user = new User("adminqaphi");
            user.CustomerID = TestConfig.ClientID;

            var classes = typeof(KPIWebPartBase)
                .Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(KPIWebPartBase)) && !t.IsAbstract );
            foreach (var c in classes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
                var instance = (KPIWebPartBase)Activator.CreateInstance(c);
                foreach (var billingMetric in Enum.GetValues(typeof(BillingMetric)))
                {
                    instance.CurrentUser = user;
                    instance.BillingMetric = (BillingMetric)billingMetric;

                    if (instance is StartEndKPIWebPartBase)
                    {
                        var startEndKPI = (StartEndKPIWebPartBase)instance;
                        startEndKPI.StartDate = new DateTime(2007, 1, 1);
                        startEndKPI.EndDate = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1);
                    }

                    instance.InitializeOnAdd();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create interfaces for them (if possible) and use [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) to create Mocks or stubs for the external dependencies.

What behavior does InvokeAllWidgets() test?

Response to comment:
I think you should mock the database as well, so that you just test the "internal" logic of the code(unit). Otherwise you will en up testing the database, and I guess that is not what you want to. And if you do call the database, what happens if some data in it changes? Will that fail your tests? If so I think you are doing integration tests and not unit tests. In a unit test try to mock all external dependencies and test your own logic (what can go wrong?). If your code don't allow you test it like, then change it!

Comment: It calls the database to get some values. Then it assigns the values to the controls on the form. My tests crash right now when it goes to assign the values to the form fields.

Comment: I think you should mock the database as well, so that you just test the "internal" logic of the code(unit).